# Update Vue Prop inside component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `Client` component that contains a `ClientInfo` and `ClientForm` component. Client has a `client` in its data and passes it to both the form and info as a prop. Inside the `ClientForm` component I have a method to handle the backend. Now when I try and do this:

```
axios.put(url, body).then(res => {
  this.client = res.data
})
```

I get the error message about directly mutating props and how I shouldn't do it. Now currently I do this:

```
axios.put(url, body).then(res => {
  Object.keys(res.data).forEach((i) => {
    if(this.client[i] != res.data[i]){
      this.client[i] = res.data[i]
    }
  })
})
```

Which seems... well kind of sub-optimal.

Is there a better way to handle updating the `client` object from the `ClientForm` so that the `ClientInfo` component gets the new info?

Comment: thanks guys. Yes this means this is absolutely a duplicate of the other questions, I just didn't know this $emit was a thing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could emit a custom event with the new data:

```
axios.put(url, body).then(res => {
  this.$emit('client', res.data)
})
```

...and then react to that event in your **Client** parent component to update its state:

```
<ClientForm @client='(data) => client = data' />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: See also [the `.sync` modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier)